# Excel formula is giving me an answer in date format instead of a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data looks like this

[image]

Essentially I need to get the earliest buy date and subtract from all the sell dates for the same account number. To get the earliest buy date, I used the following formula:

```
=MINIFS(G:G,C:C,C53,E:E,"Buy")
```

`G` is the column where all the dates are, `C` is is where the account numbers are and column `E` is where the BUY and SELLs are located.

However when I do this formula

```
==SUMIFS(H:H,C:C,C48,E:E,"Buy")-H48
```

It is giving me a date number instead of the difference between two dates. Any ideas why?

Comment: In Excel, the difference between two dates is a date. Since each date is expressed as a number, deducting one date from another returns a number. Since Excel thinks that the result is a date it will show that number as a date unless instructed to show another format. Therefore, before you accuse Excel of fanciful calculations try your hand at cell formatting. `Date-Date` will be displayed as `Date` if the cell format is `General`. Set a cell format for numbers to show a number instead.

Comment: I did put the format as Number and its giving me a number of -43703.00 instead of 2 which i want in my case

Comment: 43703 = 26  Aug 2019. Therefore it looks like your SUMIFS returns quite a small number from which a date within your range (H48) is deducted to give a negative result.